# Google Sheets if Cell Value matches then return a corresponding value in a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a "Homework" sheet and a "Student" sheet. The homework sheet is essentially a rubric where I input data and it generates the total score for an individual student. The Student sheet has the roster for the class in column A, and each following column corresponds to a homework assignment (Homework 1, Homework 2, ect).

On the "Homework" sheet I would like to press a button and run a script to:

1. Match the student name in the "Homework" sheet cell B3 with the student name in the "Student" sheet, somewhere in column A.
2. Copy and paste the score of that student, found in Homework cell G3, and paste to the column that is associated with the current homework assignment. Homework assignment name in the "Homework" sheet is in cell B1, and the homework assignment name in the "Student" sheet are the column headings.

I am new to scripts in Google Sheets and imagine this would be some sort of index/match.

Any ideas to get started?

Comment: For documentation reasons please accept the answer or provide your feedback in order to modify it and solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
function addScores(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const h_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Homework');
  const s_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Student');
  
  const h_homework = h_sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const h_student = h_sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  const h_score = h_sheet.getRange('G3').getValue();
   
  const s_students = s_sheet.getRange(2,1,s_sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  const s_homeworks = s_sheet.getRange(1,1,1,s_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  
  const s_student_pos = s_students.indexOf(h_student)+2;
  const s_homework_pos = s_homeworks.indexOf(h_homework)+1;
  
  s_sheet.getRange(s_student_pos,s_homework_pos).setValue(h_score);
}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Scores')
  .addItem('Add new score', 'addScores')
  .addToUi();
}
```

---

### Instructions:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: script editor]

2. **Copy and Paste** the aforementioned code snippet here and click **save**:

[image: editor]

3. **Refresh** your sheet and you will see a new button (Scores) appeared in the top bar:

[image: menu]

---

### Illustration:

[image: illustration]